# STXXL: limited parallelism during sorting?

Tags: sorting, stxxl

I populate a very large array using a `stxxl::VECTOR_GENERATOR<MyData>::result::bufwriter_type` (something like 100M entries) which I need to sort in parallel.

I use the `stxxl::sort(vector->begin(), vector->end(), cmp(), memoryAmount)` method, which in theory should do what I need: sort the elements very efficiently.

However, during the execution of this method I noticed that only one processor is fully utilised, and all the other cores are quite idle (I suspect there is little activity to fetch the input, but in practice they don't do anything).

This is my question: is it possible to exploit more cores during the sorting phase, or is the parallelism used only to fetch the input asynchronously? If so, are there documents that explain how to enable it? (I looked extensively the documentation on the website, but I couldn't find anything).

Thanks very much!

**EDIT**

Thanks for the suggestion. I provide below some more information.

First of all I use MacOs for my experiments. What I do is that I launch the following program and I study its behaviour.

```
typedef struct Triple {
    long t1, t2, t3;

    Triple(long s, long p, long o) {
        this->t1 = s;
        this->t2 = p;
        this->t3 = o;
    }

    Triple() {
        t1 = t2 = t3 = 0;
    }
} Triple;

const Triple minv(std::numeric_limits<long>::min(),
        std::numeric_limits<long>::min(), std::numeric_limits<long>::min());

const Triple maxv(std::numeric_limits<long>::max(),
        std::numeric_limits<long>::max(), std::numeric_limits<long>::max());

struct cmp: std::less<Triple> {
    bool operator ()(const Triple& a, const Triple& b) const {
        if (a.t1 < b.t1) {
            return true;
        } else if (a.t1 == b.t1) {
            if (a.t2 < b.t2) {
                return true;
            } else if (a.t2 == b.t2) {
                return a.t3 < b.t3;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    Triple min_value() const {
        return minv;
    }

    Triple max_value() const {
        return maxv;
    }
};

typedef stxxl::VECTOR_GENERATOR<Triple>::result vector_type;

int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
    vector_type vector;
    vector_type::bufwriter_type writer(vector);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000000; ++i) {
        if (i % 10000000 == 0)
            std::cout << "Inserting element " << i << std::endl;
        Triple t;
        t.t1 = rand();
        t.t2 = rand();
        t.t3 = rand();
        writer << t;
    }
    writer.finish();

    //Sort the vector
    stxxl::sort(vector.begin(), vector.end(), cmp(), 1024*1024*1024);

    std::cout << vector.size() << std::endl;
}
```

Indeed there seems to be only one or maximum two threads working during the execution of this program. Notice that the machine has only a single disk.

Can you please confirm me whether the parallelism work on macos? If not, then I will try to use linux to see what happens. Or is perhaps because there is only one disk?

Comment: Sorry, I dont get notification mails for changed questions.

The answer is no: there is no support for parallel sorting on MacOSX, because we use gcc's parallel algorithms, and MacOSX has clang.

Answer (score 1):

In principle what you are doing should work out-of-the-box. With everything working you should see all cores doing processing.

Since it doesnt work, we'll have to find the error, and debugging why we see no parallel speedups is still tricky business these days.

The main idea is to go from small to large examples:

- what platform is this? There is no parallelism on MSVC, only on Linux/gcc.
- By default STXXL builds on Linux/gcc with USE_GNU_PARALLEL. you can turn it off to see if it has an effect.
- Try reproducing the example values shown in http://stxxl.sourceforge.net/tags/master/stxxl_tool.html  - with and without USE_GNU_PARALLEL
- See if just in memory parallel sorting scales on your processor/system.